# Hadoop-Cascading: Partial directory source tap

Tags: java, hadoop, cascading, scalding

My data have structure like this:

```
+data
|-2014080700_00.txt
|-2014080700_01.txt
|-2014080701_00.txt
|- ...
|-2014080723_00.txt
|-2014080800_00.txt
|- ...
|-2014090800_00.txt
```

I know I can use all the file inside data directory with `Tap` like below:

```
Tap inTap = new Hfs( new TextLine(), "/path/to/data");
```

But I want specific part of the directory, for example only file on date `20140807`. Hence it will include all file with prefix `20140807`. Is there any way to do it with Cascading? Or is there any way to do it with scalding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do it using [`Hfs`](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.2/javadoc/cascading/tap/hadoop/Hfs.html), but it's 
 possible using [`GlobHfs`](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.2/javadoc/cascading/tap/hadoop/GlobHfs.html).

Try the following:

```
Tap inTap = new GlobHfs( new TextLine(), "/path/to/data/", new GlobFilter("20140807*"));
```

This creates a Globbing tap, using "/path/to/data/" directory as source and filtering the files inside using `"20140807*"` glob pattern passed to [`GlobFilter`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/GlobFilter.html).

Comment: Thanks, I don't know GlobHfs exists. And from the documentation it's also accept a PathFilter object, that I assume we can create custom filter, right?

Comment: @dieend yes, just extend PathFilter.

Comment: I thought the `PathFilter` will use all files under subdirectory as arguments, given `inputPath` point to directory. Apparently I need to use `path/to/directory/*` to use all files under subdirectory as `PathFilter` arguments.